# What's the difference between [HttpGet] and [HttpGet("{id}")]?

Tags: asp.net, api

What are the differences between HTTPGET method and HTTPGET("{id}") method?
What is the API method that is used to update table columns?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return new JsonResult(users);
}

// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(string id)
{
    return new JsonResult(response);
}
```

Comment: How about [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing-with-httpverb-attributes)?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) in Web API.

The first method is routing to a clean api:

```
/api/controller
```

The second specifies route value in the attribute and will be called via the following url:

```
/api/controller/5
```

The second one is normally used to update existing queries, as you specify specific value in the route whilst the first specifies nothing.

Comment: just click the accepted answer, so this question will set, glad to help :)

Comment: Can I know how do you call the [HttpGet("{id}")] method using ajax?

Comment: in the url you specify "/api/controller/" + id